# How can I use a Wii remote as a remote control for Keynote on my mid-2011 MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, keynote

I have a Wii Remote and a mid-2011 MacBook Air. What do I do to pair the Wii remote with the Air, and what software can accept input from this Bluetooth device and send it to Keynote?

I'm looking for much more than a link to a piece of software. What software do you use, how do you go about setting up the pairing, and how do you go about using the Wii remote?

Comment: Flick Wii-mote to advance slide? Yes please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you'll need to download Darwiin Remote form here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/darwiin-remote/. This software will allow communication between the Wii Remote and your computer.

I haven't played with this for a long time, but I believe that when I did this app allows the Wii Remote to act as your mouse and provide direct interaction with the system (I used a candle to provide the required infrared source for tracking).

Comment: Indeed, I do have the software downloaded, but have not been able to successfully sync my Wii remote, let alone use it. What do you do?

Comment: Press 1 button and 2 button simultaneously, or use the red button inside the wiimote battery compartment instead of buttons 1 and 2. Copied for [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/darwiin-remote/forums/forum/641465/topic/1769644).

Answer (score 2):

[Remote Buddy](http://www.iospirit.com/products/remotebuddy/hardware/#nintendowiiremote) supports using a Wii remote to control a Mac and lists Keynote as a [controllable application](http://www.iospirit.com/products/remotebuddy/software/). You can also customise button-presses to perform a range of different actions. Although I've never tried it with a Wii remote, I do use it with an Apple remote to control a Mac Mini as a media centre and its a great piece of software.

The [iospirit FAQ's](http://www.iospirit.com/support/faqs/remotebuddy/#faqtoc2) contain information on setting up and pairing the Wii remote. Once paired you should be able to use the Mapping tab to assign functions to the buttons, or pick from a standard set of modifiable 'behaviours'.